# Should idempotent service respond with error after first call?

Tags: web-services, service, domain-driven-design, json-rpc, idempotent

I'm writing service layer for DDD app.
Services are exposed through JSON-RPC over WSS.
I'm not sure how to respond to redundant calls to service.

**Some facts about the system:**

1. All requests must be completed within specific **time** or timeout exception occurs.
2. If system is under heavy load it may decide to **discard** request (visible as **timeout**).
3. If system is under heavy load some messages may **expire** in the queue (visible as **timeout**).
4. Even if request reaches it's destination ACK may **not reach** user in
   time (visible as **timeout**).
5. End user has right to **re-invoke** method if ACK didn't arrive in time.

No guarantees on request completion are given. 
Thus the need for idempotency.

**Problem arises if we consider [4]+[5] implications:**

- User invokes method setFoo(Bar).

  - Entity was created but ACK didn't make it on time.
- User receives timeout and assumes that he should try again, so he re-invokes setFoo(Bar).
- Entity already exists -> hmm...

Question is: **Should user get ACK or Error(I've already done that mate...)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An idempotent operation should have the same behaviour when it is called multiple times.  This suggests that the return value should be the same as well, so in the scenario you are describing above, the user should get ACK.

Consider the alternative; if you return an error to the user, then how should the user respond?  What "error handling" is appropriate?

You can make an argument for a response of **ACK(I've already done that mate...)** but the part in brackets should be a purely optional informative field, not something that affects how the user processes the response.

Comment: Arguably one could say that even if the method returns Error it does not change the state of the application(server side) and does not create side effects. Therefore we could still say it's Idempotent.

Comment: Idempotent from the server point of view, but not from the user.  Do you want the action of calling the server to be idempotent as well?

Comment: I like the idea of "metadata" in ACK. Perhaps all idempotency related errors(Exists etc.) should be attached as metadata. Thanks for that.

Comment: Yes I do. I'm worried about a scenario where information is lost about the reason for success of operation. For example: _I want to add read permission to user X. After execution I've got ACK(Mr. Y already gave that permission to user X)_. Basically intent was satisfied but operation was not successful. This type of distinction makes sense for UI in many scenarios and it's difficult to achieve otherwise.